# Extraction of multiple tags on a line

Tags: java, regex

I'll try to be clear in my explanation `^ ^`. I input a text that I read file line by line (and I've tried word by word). Once I read I apply a regular expression that works, but the output file does not suit me I get this type of output:

```
<pers> Sarkozy </pers>
<pers> Muscat </pers> , le secrétaire général , devant <pers> Sarkozy </pers>
<pers> Muscat </pers>
```

I will wish:

```
<pers> Sarkozy </pers>
<pers> Muscat </pers>
<pers> Sarkozy </pers>
<pers> Muscat </pers>
```

And I can not understand where the problem ... I feel that from the moment it matches my pattern several times it takes me a line line the entire line and not just tags ... Is my regular expression that is not good or does it come out of my way to read my files?

my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        File file = new File(
                monfichier);
        String fileContent = readFileAsString(file.getAbsolutePath());

        countNE countne = new countNE();

        String result = countne.countNE(fileContent);
         System.out.println(result);


    }

    public String countNE(String fileContent) throws java.io.IOException {
        int i = 0;
        Hashtable<String, Integer> table = new Hashtable();
        int nbOcc = 0;

        String regPerson = "<pers>.?\\w*.?</pers>";

        Pattern pPers = Pattern.compile(regPerson);

        Matcher m = pPers.matcher(fileContent);
        String result = "";

        while (m.find()) {
            String person = m.group();
            // System.out.println(person + " " + i);
            // System.out.println(person);
            i++;
            result += person + "\n";
        }
        return result;

    }

    public static String readFileAsString(String filePath)
            throws java.io.IOException {
        String chaine = "";
        // lecture du fichier texte
        try {
            InputStream ips = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(ips);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ipsr);
            String ligne;
            while ((ligne = br.readLine()) != null) {
                chaine += ligne + "\n";

            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(chaine);
        return chaine;
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Regexes are not for this. Did you consider nested tags? Use a parser instead.

Comment: Can you convert your code from reading from a file to just using a hard-coded string instead (so we can have an easily reproducible example)? Using `StringReader` should make this change easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the

```
.?
```

in your regex.
It matches anything, including `<pers>` and `</pers>`.
So in order to get what you want, you might split the line up first or exclude `<pers>` from `.` by using a shorter interval of characters for matching (e.g. `[a-zA-Z]` or similar).

Comment: `.?` is a single optional character, so it can't match `<pers>` or `</pers>`.

Answer (score 0):

The right way:

```
public static String countNE(String fileContent) throws java.io.IOException {
    Hashtable<String, Integer> table = new Hashtable();
    int nbOcc = 0;

    String regPerson = "(<pers>.*?</pers>)";
    // String regPerson = "(<.*>.*?</.*>)";

    Pattern pPers = Pattern.compile(regPerson);

    Matcher m = pPers.matcher(fileContent);
    String result = "";
    while(m.find())
    {
            result += m.group(1);
    }

    return result;
}
```